# Find Particular File Types

Tags: c#

I've encountered an peculiar issue when utilizing `System.IO`.  When you iterate through a directory for a file with a type of `File`, without an extension, the file isn't detected.

```
// Successful:
var files = DirectoryInfo(server.Path).GetFiles("sitemap*.*);
var contents = Directory.GetFiles(server.Path, "sitemap*.*", ...);
```

The above code would suffice in most instances, however if you have other types with identical name, they'll be collected as well.

Our issue is encountered when you only want the `sitemap.file`.

```
// Invalid Code:
var files = DirectoryInfo(server.Path).GetFiles("sitemap*.file);
var contents = Directory.GetFiles(server.Path, "sitemap*.file", ...);
var examples = DirectoryInfo(server.Path).GetFiles("sitemap*);
```

The array is empty, it doesn't find any of the raw `.file` extension files.  I'm assuming the issue occurs because it doesn't actually have an extension.

How do you circumvent this limitation?

**Update:**  I know I could do something along these lines with `FileInfo[]`, but was hoping to find a more simple approach then iteration, then compare with:

```
var files = DirectoryInfo(server.Path).GetFiles("sitemap*.*);
foreach(var file in files)
     if(file.Extension != ".gz" && file.Extension != ".xml")
     {
          // Do something with File.
     }
```

Especially if you have a wide assortment of extensions within your directory. You would think it would account for such a type, or lack there of.

[image: Multiple]
[image: Empty Array]

Comment: Not really sure what is going on, This line `var contents = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test", "sitemap*.file");` should return you all the files ending in with your criteria. Just tried your code and and it is working as expected.

Comment: i think he is talking about files called something like 'sitemap' with no extension. Is that right Greg?

Comment: ", but Windows assigns a raw .File extension since it doesn't know how to handle it either" . No it doesn't. Take a look at your folder in Windows explorer. Can you put name of an actual file in your question, that should match its criteria.

Comment: I think you can use `sitemap*.` (with no `*` after the `.`)

Comment: Windows does not assign .file to a file without an extension.  I believe you are confusing the type specified in that column in windows explorer with the actual extension behind the scenes (nothing).  If you used `"sitemap*"` it should locate the files you are looking for since that doesn't specify an extension.

Comment: @JNYRanger I understand that it will find it, but it also grabs all other files that match:  sitemap.gz, sitemap,xml, sitemap, and etc.  I only want `sitemap`.

Comment: @Greg You'd need to filter those out later since the filtering features in System.IO.File only allows for a single inclusive simple filter.

Comment: @Greg - are you sure `var files = DirectoryInfo(server.Path).GetFiles("sitemap*.");` doesn't work? It seems to be working for me (on win7)

Comment: @Greg I did, but you said you didn't want to use `FileInfo` (and I'm assuming `DirectoryInfo`) to iterate & check manually.  @Petelids comment should work for you though since the . char at the end without an asterisk indicates nothing afterwards

Comment: This is why you shouldn't code at 4 AM, you overlook basic things.  `Sitemap*.` does indeed works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are looking to search files starting with `sitemap` and doesn't have any extension. Use `"sitemap*."` pattern.

```
var contents = Directory.GetFiles(server.Path, "sitemap*.");
```

**Notice the last dot** (.) in the pattern, that specifies to get those files which doesn't have any extension associated with it.

This will give you files like:

```
sitemap1
sitemap2
```

and will exclude files like:

```
sitemap1.gz
sitempa2.gz
```

Comment: Your correct, in my example I kept overlooking the `.` when I did the pattern.  So when I did `sitemap*` it grabbed all.

Comment: @Greg, also enable file extensions in your windows explorer, that will let you see the actual file extension these files have, so you will know that Windows doesn't add a `.FILE` extension for *raw* files. *(files without extension)*

Comment: Yeah, thats what happens when you code at 4AM and your half awake.

Answer (score 1):

The file *doesn't* have an extension. Configure your Explorer to not hide extensions and you'll see.

If you're only looking for extensionless files, change your `if` to:

```
 if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.Extension))
```